# Node Proxy - 404 page not found

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

I am trying to use node proxy API by using API call http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{name} but I am getting "404 page not found" when I pass a valid node name on all verbs (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTION, PATCH) except HEAD, and when invalid node name passed in parameter it returns a proper kubernetes object.

```
{
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "nodes \"kube-master1\" not found",
    "reason": "NotFound",
    "details": {
        "name": "kube-master1",
        "kind": "nodes"
    },
    "code": 404
}
```

It look like kubernetes is trying to access any service which is not properly configured. any idea which service I need to configure to make it run.

Thanks,

Comment: In the snipet that you paste above seems K8S doesn't find the node. Probably the node can't comunicate with the `kube-master`.

Comment: yes, I get that snipet when I provide invalid node (which is a proper kubernetes object) but when I pass a valid node it returns me "404 page not found" (just a plain text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely because you need to specify the port on the node to connect to. Depending on what you are trying to do you can try the following endpoints to check that the proxy is working correctly:

- Metrics: 
  http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{nodeName}:10250/metrics
- Stats: http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{nodeName}:10250/stats
- CAdvisor: http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{nodeName}:4194/

You can encrypt the connections from the apiserver to the node by [prefixing `https:` to the node name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication#apiserver---nodes-pods-and-services).

Go [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls) for further details related specifically to accessing Services via the apiserver proxy.

Comment: thanks for providing above endpoints. Can you please aso guide me about the difference between `http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{nodeName}` and `http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/nodes/{nodeName}/proxy`

Comment: and also about http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{nodeName}/{path}

Comment: @MuhammadTahirHassan they are exactly the same AFAIK

Comment: if both are same then http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/nodes/{nodeName}/proxy:4194/ this call have to give me the same CAdvisor Screen but this call is returning me 404 the server could not find the requested resource

Comment: @MuhammadTahirHassan the port needs to go just after the node name - http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/nodes/{nodeName}:4194/proxy/

Comment: ok and can you please also guide me about http://{endpoint:port}/api/v1/proxy/nodes/{nodeName}/{path}. what is the value of path.

Comment: @MuhammadTahirHassan the connections made from the apiserver to the nodes are HTTP connections, so path is the HTTP path you want to hit on the node